# After migrating the oracle apex application from 19.2 version to 21.2 version, Captcha is not visible on login page

Tags: html, css, oracle-apex

After migrating the oracle apex application from Version 19.2 to Version 21.2, Login page captcha not visible through this code

```html
<div style="background-color:#FFF;border:1px solid #ececec;padding:3px;">
<img width="30" height="30",=""src="APEX_210200.wwv_flow_image_generator.get_image?p_position=1&p_sessionid=&APP_SESSION.">
<img width="30" height="30",=""src="APEX_210200.wwv_flow_image_generator.get_image?p_position=2&p_sessionid=&APP_SESSION.">
<img width="30" height="30",=""src="APEX_210200.wwv_flow_image_generator.get_image?p_position=3&p_sessionid=&APP_SESSION.">
<img width="30" height="30",=""src="APEX_210200.wwv_flow_image_generator.get_image?p_position=4&p_sessionid=&APP_SESSION.">
<img width="30" height="30",=""src="APEX_210200.wwv_flow_image_generator.get_image?p_position=5&p_sessionid=&APP_SESSION.">
</div>
```

Comment: Please add more detail about your problem. What did you do so far and any relevant code if any.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: And what's your question now? How is this related to HTML or CSS?